# Date Format for Macro

Tags: excel, vba, date

I wrote a Macro to simplify a process at work.

I am trying to figure out how to fix this date so when the macro is run it isn't missing an "."

ex) [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbaR9.png]

here is my code:

```
 Dim currentDate As String
    currentDate = Left(Replace(Date, "/", "."), 5) + Right(Date, 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

To format date as a string use `Format` function and specify the format in a string. For instance:

```vb
Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") 'gives 2020-01-08
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should add the desired dot:

```
Dim currentDate As String currentDate = Left(Replace(Date, "/", "."), 5) & "." & Right(Date, 2)
```

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear it!!

Comment: Probably better to use `&` instead of `+`.